# Blocking FixedThreadPool

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I have an application that makes use of a FixedThreadPool with 10 threads for running database queries. If there is a constant high number of queries to perform it starts to use a significant amount of memory and queries start taking longer to be executed.

Is there a way of making a FixedThreadPool block when all threads are in use or when the queue reaches a certain size so that I don't end up with this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by blocking the FixedThreadPool?

Comment: @Neo When a task is submitted to the pool it blocks if it cannot execute the task or the queue is larger than a certain size.

Comment: How does that improve anything?

Comment: You can use the `ThreadPoolExecutor` with a Bounded Queue. Also it allows you to register a `RejectedExecutionHandler` for tasks that cannot be queued(once the queue or max threads are saturated). See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html